# How to check last modify of a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database preinstalled. I don't wont modify it. Does exist a built in method to check which and when a field has been modified in a specific table?

Comment: Maybe this could help http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no built in method that does this in MySQL.

If you want this type of operation performed in the database, you would need to roll your own solution; and that would require you to modify the database, by adding tables and triggers to audit changes, for example.